# Singular locus of orientable 3-orbifolds

Tags: reference-request, orbifolds

Any reference (or any hints if the proof is easy) for the proof that the singular locus of a 3-dimensional orientable orbifold is a trivalent graph with each edge labelled by integers $a,b,c>1$ and if edges meet at a vertex then $1/a+1/b+1/c>1$ namely, there is a nbhd of the vertex which is a cone over an orientable spherical 2-orbifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is easy. Use classification of 2-dimensional oriented spherical orbifolds.

Edit: every n-dimensional orbifold is locally a cone over a spherical orbifold of dimension n-1. Every spherical 2-dimensional oriented orbifold is either the sphere with two cone points or sphere with three cone points satisfying the inequality you mentioned (sum of inverses of their orders is $>1$).

Comment: I didn't know that every n-dimensional orbifold is locally a cone over a spherical orbifold of dimension n-1. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Test123: This is immediate from the definition, as the (locally) quotient of the round ball by a finite group of orthogonal transformations. This group preserves the concentric spheres.

Comment: The use of the notion of trivalent graph is just a way of describing that inequility or there is more details into that?

Comment: @Test123: The trivalent graph is (locally) a cone over a 3-point set; the inequalities are just the inequalities for the 2d spherical orbifolds.